# Use a previous row value on where clause

Tags: sql-server

I've got a table with a simple structure `dhRegistro` (DATETIME) and `marcha` (Boolean) I need to obtain the `dhRegistro` column of the rows which the previous row `marcha` column it's 1 (true).

```
   dhRegistro              | marcha
   ----------------------------------
   2020-06-15 12:28:17.043  | 1
   2020-06-15 12:43:46.803  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 12:44:20.143  | 0
   2020-06-15 14:01:22.893  | 0
   2020-06-15 14:01:22.920  | 0
   2020-06-15 14:01:23.030  | 0
   2020-06-15 14:02:55.937  | 0
   2020-06-15 14:04:05.693  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 14:23:19.817  | 0
   2020-06-15 14:57:02.027  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 15:13:02.143  | 0
   2020-06-15 15:20:08.200  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 15:39:22.333  | 0
   2020-06-15 15:50:36.430  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 16:06:35.557  | 0
   2020-06-15 16:08:18.527  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 16:27:32.687  | 0
   2020-06-15 16:36:21.763  | 1
   2020-06-15 16:51:46.587  | 1
-> 2020-06-15 17:11:12.000  | 0
   2020-06-15 17:20:01.007  | 1
   2020-06-15 17:35:27.313  | 1
```

I don't know how to get the previous row value to use in the where clause and obtain only the rows with an arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CTE or subquery to analize (you cannot use window functions directly in WHERE clause) and then filter it.

CTE example:

```
WITH ExTable AS (SELECT 
  dhRegistro, 
  marcha, 
  LAG(marcha) OVER (ORDER BY dhRegistro) as lastMarcha
FROM Table)

SELECT dhRegistro, marcha
FROM ExTable
WHERE marcha = 0 AND lastMarcha = 1
```

Comment: I think you wanted to say "WHERE marcha = 0 AND lastMarcha = 1"